# Hiding IOS keyboard suggestion bar appearing above custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-keyboard, autocorrect

I am developing a custom keyboard extension app, but apple keyboard native autocorrection and suggestion does not function with my app. The native autocorrection and suggestion bar is empty and appears persistently above my custom keyboard. I am trying to hide it to create my own with my suggestion list.

The problem is I did not find the way to hide the native suggestion bar.

```
 UITextInputAssistantItem *item = [textInput.textInputView inputAssistantItem];  
 item.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];  
 item.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```

does not work because my custom keyboard does not use a **textInput**. My custom keyboard works with external text input fields like for example Safari search field using **self.textDocumentProxy**

Also

```
self.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups = @[];  
self.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups = @[];
```

does not work.

Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: textInput.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
not work?

Comment: myTextView.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;

Comment: Thank you Nguyen Hoan and @HimanshuMoradiya, no it does not work mainly because my application does not use any text view like textInput or myTextView. And even if it used a textView, UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo only hides the autocorrection from the suggestion bar, not the suggestion bar itself. Furthermore, the autocorrect feature is anyway not available for custom keyboards. So what I get persistently is an empty suggestion bar, that I would like to get rid of.